# Count number of Special Character in Unix Shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, hex

I have a delimited file that is separated by octal \036 or Hexadecimal value 1e.

I need to count the number of delimiters on each line using a bash shell script.

I was trying to use awk, not sure if this is the best way.

Sample Input (| is a representation of \036)

```
Example|Running|123|
```

Expected output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F'|' '{print NF-1}' file
```

Change `|` to whatever separator you like. If your file can have empty lines then you need to tweak it to:

```
awk -F'|' '{print (NF ? NF-1 : 0)}' file
```

Comment: Is it possible for NF to be 0? I can't find any definite specification but since FS *separates* fields, you can certainly have one field with no FS. The only possible line without a field would be an empty line, afaics, but that seems to be treated as a single empty field rather than no fields.

Comment: Yes, `echo "" | awk '{print NF}'` outputs `0` because an empty line has no fields and so the Number of Fields is zero. The same is true if the line only contains blanks and you're using the default FS (a blank char) since field splitting with the default FS strips off leading and trailing blanks before splitting the record into fields and obviously there's nothing left of an all-blank line after leading/trailing blanks are removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
awk '{print gsub(/\|/,"")}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try

```
awk -F"|" '{print substr($3,length($3))}' OFS="|"   Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Making field separator `-F` as `|` and then printing the 3rd column by doing `$3` only as per your need. Then setting `OFS`(output field separator) to `|`. Finally mentioning Input_file name here.

Comment: I think this just prints the 3rd column? Also, the separator should be \036?

Comment: @Defcon, changed now, please change -F"|" to -F"\036" and let me know if this helps you?

Answer (score 0):

This will work as far as I know

```
echo "Example|Running|123|" | tr -cd '|' | wc -c
```

#### Output

`3`

Answer (score 0):

Awk may not be the best tool for this.  Gnu grep has a cool -o option that prints each matching pattern on a separate line.  You can then count how many matching lines are generated for each input line, and that's the count of your delimiters.  E.g. (where ^^ in the file is actually hex 1e)

```
$ cat -v i
a^^b^^c
d^^e^^f^^g

$ grep -n -o $'\x1e' i | uniq -c
      2 1:
      3 2:
```

if you remove the uniq -c you can see how it's working.  You'll get "1" printed twice because there are two matching patterns on the first line.  Or try it with some regular ascii characters and it becomes clearer what the -o and -n options are doing.

If you want to print the line number followed by the field count for that line, I'd do something like:

```
$grep -n -o $'\x1e' i | tr -d ':' | uniq -c | awk '{print $2 " " $1}'
1 2
2 3
```

This assumes that every line in the file contains at least one delimiter.  If that's not the case, here's another approach that's probably faster too:

```
$ tr -d -c $'\x1e\n' < i | awk '{print length}'
2
3
0
0
0
```

This uses tr to delete (-d) all characters that are not (-c) 1e or \n.  It then pipes that stream of data to awk which just counts how many characters are left on each line.  If you want the line number, add " | cat -n" to the end.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
awk -F '\036' '{print NF-1}' file

3
```

`-F '\036'` sets input field delimiter as octal value `036`